# OSX 10.6.7 VPN client only connects once

Tags: macos, vpn

I'm experiencing an odd problem when connecting from a MacBook Pro to a macMini runing OS X server.The client will only let me connect to the server once. If I disconnect, then I have to recreate the vpn adapter in the client. Anyone else seeing this?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same issue on 10.6.8. I logged into VPN via the native IPSec VPN client, logged out, and could not log back in. I then switched to a 4.9.xx version of Cisco VPN Client, but was not able to log into the same VPN.

My friend tried the same but with a different VPN and was able to connection/disconnect/connect.

I think your issue is coming from either your computer's VPN settings, or more likely the VPN server settings.

============ UPDATE ================

Long after writing the my first response, I just wanted to confirm the root cause of the issue I was experiencing. The server side of the VPN server did not allow the same user to log-in within a 5 minute interval. I bet this is common, and therefore might be the same issue you are experiencing.